# handling lite apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Hey guys ive got an app in appstore its called GPSReminds.

I created a new project called GPSReminds Free so its a new project but its got the same content, except that you can get only 3 reminders so its kind of a lite version
How can i handle this??
What i was doing is keeping a record of how many reminders has the user already got in the document folder where you store the app.plist so when u get 3 reminders it will ask you to buy the full version to keep reminding you.
But, the big question: What happens if the user reaches the 3 reminders but then he deletes the free app and redownloads it from the appstore?? does the app.plist stays in his iphone so when he downloads it again the app will tell him he reached the 3 reminders? or does this app.plist is also deleted when he deleted the app???
Dunno if you got me, i really suck writing in english i speak spanish.
I mean the user could delete the app everytime he reaches the third reminder, or will the app.plist stay in his iphone so he will have to buy the other app wich is the full one.

Tank you very much!

Comment: Actually implementing this seems well explained in the answers. But I'm not sure apple will be OK with an app that simply stops working once it's used 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, he'll be able to get around the limit by deleting and reinstalling. The best (only?) way to handle this would be to create a unique ID for each device and store that ID with the number of reminders on a server somewhere.

You could also store the number of reminders in iCloud, but then the user must have iCloud enabled, and the iCloud info can always be deleted too, so that's probably not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your App uses some sort of external server to control the reminders and to monitor who has installed the App there is no way you can stop a user deleting and re-installing a lite version of your App.

I know you are trying to protect revenue loss from the paid version of the App.  But this is where you have to balance price versus convenience.  If the user feels that deleting and installing the App over and over again is worth their time then they will.  But if the price is low enough then they will buy the app.

But I would guess that if a user finds your App so useful that they are willing to reload it over and over again then at some point they will feel that the $$ cost is cheaper than their time.

My advice would be to do nothing to the lite version except limit it to the 3 reminders.  But for the paid version I would release a newer version that adds more useful features that you can't get in the lite version. For example share lists of things to do between people and keep track of what is done (and for that suggestion I only want a 10% cut of your profits :D )